# How do I get my LaunchAgent to run as root?

Tags: macos, root, launchd

I want to run a process as root at user login.

I created `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/eXist.plist` with `rx—r—r—` permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
        <key>GroupName</key>
        <string>wheel</string>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>eXist DB</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/Applications/eXist-db/bin/startup.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/eXist DB.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/eXist DB.out</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>root</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

However, my process continues to run as my user `davea` instead of root.  Any ideas what else I need to do?

I’m using Mac 10.9.1.

Comment: It is odd to run something as root that should run after a particular user logs in - why can't the database start at boot as other root things would do

Answer (score 8):

To get a user LaunchAgent executing a script to run as root you have to do the following:

Modify the permissions of the script. Add the script (or command) to the sudoers file in the context of the user and finally add and load a proper launch agent plist.

**This approach might create severe security holes!**

---

In the example below I use the startup.sh of eXit-db 2.2:

- Create a plist:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>Disabled</key>
      <false/>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>org.eXist_DB</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
      <array>
          <string>/usr/bin/sudo</string>
          <string>/Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Resources/eXist-db/bin/startup.sh</string>
      </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
      <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
      <string>/tmp/eXist_DB.err</string>
      <key>StandardOutPath</key>
      <string>/tmp/eXist_DB.out</string>
      <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
      <integer>10</integer>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

  and save it as *org.eXist_DB.plist* in ~/Library/LaunchAgents

  The last key:

  ```
      <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
      <integer>10</integer>
  ```

  might not be necessary. In my VM it was - for unknown reasons.
- Modify the permissions of startup.sh:

  ```
  sudo chown root /Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Resources/eXist-db/bin/startup.sh
  sudo chmod 4755 /Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Resources/eXist-db/bin/startup.sh
  ```
- Modify the sudoers file:

  ```
  sudo visudo
  ```
- add a line to enable executing a command without the need to enter the sudo  password

  ```
  # User privilege specification
  root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
  %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
  ```

  ->

  ```
  # User privilege specification
  root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
  %admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
  your_user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Applications/eXist-db.app/Contents/Resources/eXist-db/bin/startup.sh
  ```
- Finally enter:

  ```
  launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.eXist_DB.plist
  ```

  to load and start the launch agent

Comment: this is a superb answer, have all the upvotes ;)

Answer (score 4):

Add the key value pair for `UserName`:

```
<key>UserName</key>
<string>root</string>
```

Place the [launchd job ticket](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`; the `/System` folder is reserved exclusively for Apple's use.

To run as the specified user, be sure to place the job ticket in `LaunchDaemons`. As @Manu mentions in the comment below, the `UserName` key is ignored for jobs in `LaunchAgents`.

Comment: For the record, changing the 'UserName' key doesn't affect a LaunchAgent, it will still run as the logged in user.

Comment: The question refers specifically to LaunchAgents and running a process after login. LaunchDaemons are a bad fit for processes that rely on things that are only available after login, like a GUI, and as @Manu pointed out this answer does not work for LaunchAgents.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loginhook. They're deprecated but still work:

[Mac OS X: Creating a login hook](https://support.apple.com/HT2420)

Comment: This is not properly tested and doesn't work (at least with the example above and for me)!

Comment: and the link is now broken

Answer (score 1):

You can use [launchd-oneshot](https://github.com/cybertk/launchd-oneshot) to install a login job run as root with

```
brew install cybertk/formulae/launchd-oneshot
sudo launchd-oneshot <script> --on-login-as-root
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a LaunchAgent that runs with sudo/root privileges can be done by simply having `sudo` be the command that the LaunchAgent executes.

## Create PList File

Try placing this minimal example in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.sudoexample.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.sudoexample</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>sudo</string>
            <string>touch</string>
            <string>/tmp/sudoexample</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/sudoexample.log</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/sudoexample.log</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

<sub>Note: Agents should typically have user file ownership, but `root` ownership seems to work just fine as well.</sub>

The above example runs `sudo touch /tmp/sudoexample` and logs the output to `/tmp/sudoexample.log`.

If you run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.sudoexample.plist` at this point, it will fail because `sudo` will try to prompt for a password and `launchctl` doesn't have any associated `tty` to serve the password prompt:

```
$ ls /tmp/
sudoexample.log
$ cat /tmp/sudoexample.log
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

## Allow Elevated Privileges

We need to grant your user permission to run `sudo touch` without a password.

This can be done like so:

`echo "$(whoami) ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: $(which touch)" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/touch`

When you're done, the file should look something like this:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/touch
coryklein ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/touch
```

## Test It Out

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.sudoexample.plist
$ ls -l /tmp
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      wheel 0 Jun 29 14:01 sudoexample
-rw-r--r-- 1 coryklein wheel 0 Jun 29 14:01 sudoexample.log
```

Now you can see the LaunchAgent successfully ran by creating the root owned `/tmp/sudoexample`.

<sub>Thanks to [klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath)'s answer for providing the foundation for this one.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

- Don’t mess with anything in `/System/` unless you want to risk screwing up your system. Seriously. Stay away.
- Put it in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` instead.

Comment: The problem with this is that it will always run before login. So if your service depends on some GUI, it will break on log-off. I am currently searching for an option run after login but as root, unfortunately without any luck, yet.