# How can I make a LaunchDaemon run an app at login?

Tags: catalina, launchd, startup, plist, daemons

I have an internally-maintained macOS app for my macOS Catalina-based enterprise environment which:

- Must run as root (it accesses a privileged device API)
- Runs in the background without a UI (via LSUIElement key set to true in its Info.plist)
- Must run for every user who logs into a workstation without manual configuration (e.g. no manual Login Item configuration)

Creating a LaunchDaemon to launch the app seemed to be the right way to accomplish this. However, the app process is found to be hanging after first user login, presumably because it tries to start too early before app/window-supporting libraries are available (I thought setting LSUIElement to true would avoid this, but I guess not. If there's another Info.plist setting for the app I should use to accomplish this, I'm all ears). There are no errors related to the process or launchd service observed in system.log.

I've observed after login that if I kill the hanging process and the LaunchDaemon restarts it, it then works fine. So, all I think I need is a way to setup my LaunchDaemon plist so that the LaunchDaemon only launches the app on user login like a LaunchAgent, (which I can't use because LaunchAgents can't run as root). Does anyone have a tried and true plist configuration which accomplishes this? Maybe via setting a certain WatchPath for the LaunchDaemon?

My current plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my.app</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/mydaemons/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Why *must* it run as root?

Comment: @Tetsujin it accesses the privileged FSEvents API via the `/dev/fsevents` device

Comment: You should be able to run in as an agent (put the plist in /Library/LaunchAgents) and still have administrator privileges. LaunchDaemons are meant to run entirely independently of any user context, so if you're trying to launch an app within a user context you're going to run into problems. see: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW1-SW1)

Comment: @TedWrigley no dice. [Running an app via a LaunchAgent from `/Library/LaunchAgents` runs it as the logged in user](https://superuser.com/a/36173/957847).  I can confirm as much from my own testing - my app fails to access the privileged device when launched via a LaunchAgent. There are [some hacky ways](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117148/how-do-i-get-my-launchagent-to-run-as-root) to run a LaunchAgent with root credentials, but I'd prefer not to use them as they require lifting sudo protections

Comment: Well, you're working against the way the system is set up, so you basically have a choice: (1) re-code your app so that it's not an app (in other words, as a proper background daemon) so that it can run without a login session, (2) run it as a LaunchAgent and do the hacky things you dislike, or (3) split the code into two segments, one that runs as a daemon and does the privileged stuff, and the other that runs as an agent and launches a modified app in user context.

Comment: @TedWrigley thanks, I've actyally been trying (1) this afternnon, but am finding I get the exact same behavior from my "Command Line Tool" daemon version of the app. The libraries I am using (e.g. Cocoa) clearly require a user context. I guess I will settle for (2) or (3), though I still would like to know if there's a way to configure my plist to always launch the app after user login, and if that would grant it the context it needs

Comment: @eckenrod: Hunh. I assume you've checked the ownership and privileges of your daemon. Cocoa does not (itself) require a user session, but certain frameworks or classes might. Is your code simple enough that you can post it? It's getting hard to diagnose the problem otherwise...

Comment: Could use a LoginHook... pretty sure they're still around.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy: Yeah; they're deprecated, but I believe they still work.

Comment: Thanks, @Wowfunhappy, that ended up working perfectly for me. I'll share the solution soon

Answer (score 3):

[@Wowfunhappy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/150839/wowfunhappy)'s suggestion to use a Login Hook got me the exact behavior I wanted, even if it wasn't done via a LaunchDaemon as planned. The solution:

A script (myscript.sh) to launch my app (must be executable via chmod a+x)

```
#!/bin/bash

//launch app in background (otherwise login hangs)
/path/to/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp &
```

And specifying that script as a login hook via the command:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /path/to/myscript.sh
```

My app now runs as root as needed on every user login