How to make an app start automatically at login using Daemons?
I have installed Jomo on my Mac, located at /Applications/Jomo.app, and I want it to start automatically when I log into my account. I want to create a script to make it run once I log in, without being able to change this from the Settings App.
The problem is that I’ve created a launchd LaunchDaemon to execute the program. I want the program to be executed from an administrator account (with root permissions) so that it runs for a normal user account. However, the keepalive setting is causing it to restart every 4 seconds, which is very annoying. I want it to run just once when I log in and not restart repeatedly.
Here’s the .plist file I created for launching the program with keepalive:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.jomo.start</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Applications/Jomo.app/Contents/MacOS/Jomo</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
        <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
        <string>/Applications/Jomo.app/Contents/MacOS</string>
    </dict>
</plist>

Could anyone help me modify the keepalive settings so that Jomo starts only once at login and prevent it from restarting repeatedly?
Thank you!

First, what you're trying to do won't work. You would need a launch agent, not a launch daemon, and it would just invoke open(1) with the app bundle as argument. But that still wouldn't be what you want, because third-party launch agents can be controlled from the Settings app. Running the app as root wouldn't work at all. If you just want to block certain domains at a low level, modify the hosts(5) file, or use something less ridiculous than "Jomo" such as "SelfControl".

Here is how to run a LaunchAgent as root: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117148/how-do-i-get-my-launchagent-to-run-as-root   Be careful giving Jomo root privileges though, seems a bit excessive and a potential major security problem.
